# Shell - Awk - reading from variable

Tags: shell, awk

Is it possible to read for the awk input from variable (e.g. i) instead of file ?

```
awk 'something' temp
```

Can the 'temp' be replaced by the variable $i ? Really couldn't find it in man pages.

Comment: The standby solution that works in all shells is `echo "$variable" | awk 'something'`, but Bash provides the here-string notation which saves a pipeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your variable is a string, you can do that by using Bash [`here-string`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) notation.

```
awk 'something' <<< "$temp"
```

For example:

```
$ temp='hello:world'
$ awk -F':' '{print $2}' <<< "$temp"
world
```

If you variable is a file, then just do

```
$ cat file
hello:world
$ f='./file'
$ awk -F':' '{print $1}' "$f"
hello
```

Comment: I've got it. I have read much about it, but forgot to type 3 <<< instead of <<. Nevermind, thank you for your help. I will mark this thread as solved.

Comment: One more thing, it's <<< for variables - totally same - as < for files? Doesn't matter if in use for awk or only in shell script.

Comment: Yes, exactly, You can use it anywhere as long as your shell supports it. Here is some [referece](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument)

Answer (score 0):

In a POSIX shell without here-string support, you can use a here-doc instead:

```
awk 'something' <<EOF
$i
EOF
```

`awk 'something' <<< "$i"` is just a shortcut for the above when the here document is very short or already contained in a variable.